# How does it work ? Dot notation on null - mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

When I do:
`insert into .... values (...,#{object.intField, javaType=Integer},...)#`   then it is working - in database this column contains `null` - as expected. How does it work under hood ? I mean, that `object` is null, altohugh it works.  Where is the magic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters values are resolved from the method *org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(PreparedStatement)*

Then the magic you are looking for is here: method *org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.getValue(String)* tokenizes parameter name string, splitting on dots, and is recursively called until the end of the chain is reached **or until the current element is null**.

After that we are back to the general case: object properties values are retrieved by reflection: down to *java.lang.reflect.Field*.